# How to call Primary Category for WordPress Woocommerce

Tags: categories

I have try for several hours to solve this but I am getting nowhere.

In the class-wc-structured-data I would like to add a Markup for "brand" as on my website the brand = the parent category

`$markup['brand']       = $term = get_term_by('name', $name, 'product_cat');`

I would like to call the wooocommerce parent category. With the above code I am getting the name as "False" instead of the parent category.

Can someone help me please ?

Thanks

FYI I know little coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [**WordPress Codex**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by#Description) for the function

```
get_term_by( $field, $value, $taxonomy, $output, $filter );
```

> If `$value` does not exist, the return value will be `false`. If `$taxonomy` exists and `$field` and `$value` combinations exist, the Term will be returned.

So, you need to check the value of `$name` in your code

```
$term = get_term_by('name', $name, 'product_cat');
$markup['brand']   = $term ;
```